# Win32api - Access excel debug output

Tags: python, vba, winapi

Is there a way to access excel debug output (messages that are sent to the Immediate window with commands `Debug.Print`)?

For example - I want to receive a "test" message from VBA somewhere during the execution of the python code below.

Why - I'm trying to use python to run the VBA macro and I need to receive the feedback from macro during its execution to make sure it runs correctly.

VBA code:

```
Sub update()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 144
    Debug.Print ("test")
End Sub
```

Python code:

```py
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("excelsheet.xlsm"))
xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!update.update")
wb.Save()
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

Comment: Does `Debug.Print` output show up in [`DebugView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)? If so you could implement and attach your own debugger to intercept `OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO` [`DEBUG_EVENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-debug_event)s.

Comment: No, `Debug.Print` does not show up in DebugView, just tested it.